# How do I tell which version of Material UI to install for my react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I have react and react-dom 15.4.2 installed on the React starter kit I'm using and I'm trying to install material-ui; however, npm is telling me for the latest version of material UI (understandably) we need a higher version of React (16.0).

Is there a way for me to directly install the version of material-ui which is compatible with the dependencies currently existing in my package.json file? (i.e. I don't know which version this will be and I was wondering if there was a quick way to do this/look it up).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the peerDependencies of a npm package with `npm view <package-name>@<package version> peerDependencies`.

E.g. `npm view material-ui@0.17.3 peerDependencies` would list

```
{ react: '^15.4.0',
'react-dom': '^15.4.0',
'react-tap-event-plugin': '^2.0.1' }
```

You still would have to look up the versions from their github.

Comment: He wants to find the version of `material-ui` that is compatible with the installed version of `react`. Nothing to do with `node`

Comment: We are using the latest stable MUI (0.19.4) with React 15.6.2. Works fine.

Comment: Great answer! I had been trying to find a way to do this.

Comment: You can check the version of the installed package by running npm view @material-ui/core

Answer (score 2):

You can install your specific material-ui/core version.

**For example:**

```
npm i @material-ui/core@4.11.4
or
npm install @material-ui/core@4.11.4
```

Comment: Hello. How can I check what is the latest version of material/ui/core ?

Comment: Open the "package.json" file then you can see your installed packages and versions.

Like this: enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

You can check the latest release material-UI version on this official webpage: https://mui.com/versions/

**You can check your installed material-UI and other packages & versions.**

Open the `package.json` file then you can see your installed packages and versions.

Like this:
[image: 1]